# Merge two word lists after adding tags to base word

Tags: awk

I have 2 files and I need to merge them after checking the tag that follows after slash /

good_words file is a sub-set of words_with_tags.
I just need to find the tags and apply them to each word in good_words file.

```
good_words.txt
test
run
table
door
```

And the second file is bigger with tags and there are some words those I do not need.

```
words_with_tags.txt
new
word
test/f
run/AX
this
and
table
door/M
that
```

There are a few words like "table" those do not have any tag. I need such words along with tagged words.

```
expected.txt
test/f
run/AX
table
door/M
```

This grep solution works as expected but I am looking for some other solution because grep does not work as expected when I use non-english text.

```
# grep -f good_words.txt words_with_tags.txt
test/f
run/AX
table
door/M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {wrds[$1]; next} $1 in wrds' good_words.txt FS=/ words_with_tags.txt

test/f
run/AX
table
door/M
```

---

Or else, you may try this `grep`:

```sh
LCALL=C grep -wFf good_words.txt words_with_tags.txt

test/f
run/AX
table
door/M
```

Options are:

- `-w`: word match
- `-F`: fixed string matching without regex
- `f`: Use a file for patterns

---

Comment: Got the correct results using ripgrep with -w parameter.